# How to escape commas in exported .csv / custom .csv delimiter

Tags: data-export

I am running a report and exporting a .csv for use with our mail system.

The mail system uses comma delimiting, this causes an issue with merging when it encounters a comma in the Organization column.

For instance, If the Organization column contains Company Name, Inc. for a specific record then the merge will place Company Name in the Org column and Inc. in the following Lead Source column.

Can I setup Salesforce to escape the commas in some way, or can I configure it to use a different delimiter method for exported .csv, like pipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a quick Export as CSV test from a report. All the export values were wrapped by double-quotes.

E.g.

```
"Company Name", "Phone"
"Company Name, Inc.", "123545"
```

This should indicate that the comma in the company name isn't a delimiter. What is the mail-system? There might be something wrong with their CSV implementation.

From [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-3):

> Fields containing line breaks (CRLF), double quotes, and commas
> should be enclosed in double-quotes.

Comment: We are using phplist v3.0.5. There is an update available, doesn't say anything about this issue in the changelogs though. Suppose I will try to update.

Comment: I found [an old forum post from 2009](http://forums.phplist.com/viewtopic.php?t=5085&start=45#p62162) that suggests it is an issue with phplist. Of cource, that may no longer be the case with the latest version.

Comment: I believe it is an issue with phplist, I opened an issue ticket and they were quick to say that I was not entering the comma into the delimiter field before importing.  I assure you I was... I updated to phplist 3.6 and the issue still occurs every time. they say they are unable to reproduce it.